# Cufon Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, cufon

I cannot understand why my Cufon is not working,  All .js files load fine:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Company Name</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css?v=2" media="all">
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="includes/js/jquery-1.6.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="includes/js/cufon.js"></script>
<script src="includes/js/Springsteel_Lig_300.font.js"></script>
<script>
        window.addEvent('domready',function() {
                    Cufon.replace('header h1');
                });
</script>
<body>

<div id="container">

<header>
                <h1>Company</h1>
                <div id="logo"><a href="http://Company.co.nz/">Home</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with changing:

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready',function() {
        Cufon.replace('header h1');
    });
</script>
```

to just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('header h1');
</script>
```

It works for me after such change (using [Vegur.font.js](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/blob/master/fonts/Vegur.font.js) font, tested on Opera 11 and Google Chrome 11).

Edit:

Works as well with `Springsteel_Lig_300.font.js` font. I just donloaded [Springsteel Light](http://www.dafont.com/springsteel-light.font) font (springsteel-lig.otf) and used [that site](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) to generate in js format.

[image]